# Does something like an ASTNode Identifier exist in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, grammar-kit

I am writing a Plugin for *IntelliJ Idea* and now I need something like an *ASTNode Identifier*, it must be unique for every single Node in the AST.

*What should I use?*

Comment: why do you need unique ID for every AST node?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you need?  (I realize this is an older question, but it's considerably incomplete as it is.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing a plugin for a custom language, I would refer to this:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Developing+Custom+Language+Plugins+for+IntelliJ+IDEA#DevelopingCustomLanguagePluginsforIntelliJIDEA-ImplementingaParserandPSI

Also, you might consider developing your language plugin using:

https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit